# Adding "comma" in ignorekeys list in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator, pentadactyl

How can we add the comma character (`,`) in the `except` list of `ignorekeys` setting in vimperator?

I tried escaping it with backslash (`\`) but it didn't work:

```
:ignorekeys -except=:,/,\,,j,k
```

Is their some way to escape it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the comma into the "ignored-keys" file under /vimperator/info/default directly. The exception keys are wrapped in double quotes and comma separated, and list itself is enclosed in square brackets. Just add `,","` before the `]` where desired and save the file.

With regards to doing this through the command line, I do not know how to escape the character either.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, this does work!! However, I have another problem. I've remapped my comma (`,`) and dot(`.`) keys to switch tabs left and right respectively. I have added these keys on my exception list in ignorekeys for YouTube. Adding my comma (`,`) key to exception list does work on YouTube home page, however when YouTube plays a video, it seems to grab the comma key and it's not working. Could you help in this?